# What is the difference between change of state and change of phase?

Tags: phase-transition

The temperature remains constant during the change of state or phase? I know that the question is silly but this topic has been wrecking my nerves for quite a while.

Comment: This question has been answered in the chemistry stack exchange [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38325/difference-between-state-of-matter-and-phase).

Comment: Thank you!
but can you tell me whether temperature remains constant during the change of state or phase?

Comment: In general, both change of state and change of phase can occur without change in temperature.  Is the question being asked correctly rephrased as "Does temperature remain constant during change of state, or does temperature remain constant during change of phase?"  If so, I would say that the question is presenting a false choice, but I could be misunderstanding the question.  It would help to better understand the question to have greater context (e.g., what text is the question from?)

Comment: you've comprehended my question right. thank you for clearing my doubt !